# Can't get back into android phone after factory reset

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, factory-reset, nexus-6

I returned my phone to factory reset after I had certain issues witht he device. The factory reset was successful, however I am now prompted to the configuration menu of the phone, as expected. The only thing is, that when I select my language and wifi network, it sends me to a page saying: "This phone was factory reset and needs to be resynced with your google account". I enter my username and password. The phone then retruns me to the wifi selection where I have to redo the entire login sequence, only to return to the wifi again. I can't get into my phone anymore, is there anyone who knows what is going on.

I have a Nexus 6 running android 5.1.1
I have already tried turning it on and off again.